# How can I check if column does not have any values when left joint is used?

Tags: sql, mysql, select, join, left-join

I have two tables:

`family`:

```
| Position | Age |
| Dad      | 41  |
| Mom      | 45  |
| Daughter | 17  |
| Dog      |     |
```

and `food`:

```
| Meal         | Position |
| Steak        | Dad      |
| Salad        | Mom      |
| Spinach Soup |          | 
| Tacos        | Dad      |
```

I do the following query:

```
 `SELECT family.Position, food.Meal ".
 "FROM family LEFT JOIN food ".
    "ON family.Position = food.Position`.
```

and I get the following result:

```
Dad      - Steak
Dad      - Tacos
Mom      - Salad
Daughter -
Dog      -
```

Now I want to have only those rows that does not contain any value for food (i.e. the last two rows with Daughter and Dog). How can i get these rows? Can I use `where foof.Meal is null`? **Does the Meal column have to have certain properties to make this query possible?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there.

All that's needed now is explicitly stating that the right side of the equation should be NULL.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT   family.Position
         , food.Meal 
FROM     family LEFT JOIN 
         food ON family.Position = food.Position
WHERE    food.Meal IS NULL
```

**From the [Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)**

> If there is no matching row for the
>   right table in the ON or USING part in
>   a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns
>   set to NULL is used for the right
>   table. You can use this fact to find
>   rows in a table that have no
>   counterpart in another table:

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one solution.

One of it is adjusting your WHERE-condition, like...

```
SELECT family.Position, food.Meal 
FROM family 
LEFT JOIN food ON family.Position = food.Position
WHERE food.Meal IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "where meal is null" and it works even if "meal" is "not null".

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how to do it mysql but sql server

```
SELECT family.Position, food.Meal ". "FROM family LEFT JOIN food ". "ON family.Position != food.Position.
```